# Trying to understand representation of hex values in int form

Tags: int, hex

So there is a piece written in c++ that someone wrote that I'm trying to understand.
In the code below,how can the hex values get represented as they did in the output below?

```
r[0].x = 0x90807060;
r[0].b = 0x50;
```

//extra code here

> output:  60 70 80 90
>
> ```
>      50
> ```

What technique would be used to print 0x90807060 and 0x50 as 60 70 80 90, and 50 respectively?

Comment: Where is the code that produces that output?

Comment: What programming language is this, is there a formatting function?

Comment: I'm trying to find out how a hex value like 0x90807060 can be broken down into the values of 60 70 80 90. It's in c++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C:

```
int main()
{
    int  a = 0x90807060;
    char b = 0x50;

    // Treat a as an Array of unsigned chars, and print them 1-by-1.
    for(int i=0; i<sizeof(a); ++i)
    {
        printf("%x ", ((unsigned char*)&a)[i]);
    }

    // Print b as a Hex Value.
    printf("\n%x", b);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

***Output***

```
60 70 80 90
50
```

Answer (score 0):

You could print output like that by using the two operators >> and &.  Use shift to move the bits down to the lowest 8.  Use & to mask off those bits by anding with 0xFF.  Then print it out one 8 bit chunk at a time.

Comment: Not at all necessary on an X86 platform  (see my answer).

Comment: completely true, (although I think pretty much any platform allows what you posted) I guess I just output the first idea that came to mind since it was so trivial.  Although I do like casting to a char and using Cs indexing to handle addressing better than shifts and masks.

Comment: Not "any platform".  Only little-endian platforms, so that the 60 ends up in the "first" position.  On a big-endian platform, the 90 will end up first.

Answer (score 0):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        R[] r = new R[] { new R() };

        r[0].x = 0x90807060;
        r[0].b = 0x50;

        Console.WriteLine("{0:X2} {1:X2} {2:X2} {3:X2}", r[0].x << 24 >> 24, r[0].x << 16 >> 24, r[0].x << 8 >> 24, r[0].x >> 24);
        Console.WriteLine("{0:X2}", r[0].b);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public class R
    {
        public uint x { get; set; }
        public byte b { get; set; }
    }
```